# Deleting elements from a List

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, so I decided to code something to joke with a friend. Basically the project is about helping Anderson to reach the car. The 'A' will move in every D input from the user. I made my map a list (file Anderson.py, line 5) but I can't delete those spaces from the list. I keep having a ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list.

main:

```
from Andershow import Anderson

if __name__ == "__main__":
    anderson = Anderson
    anderson.icon = 'A'
    icon = anderson.icon
    print("Ajude o anderson a chegar até o carro!")
    anderson.print_map()

    for x in range(1, 5):
        comando = input("GO:")
        if comando == "D":
            anderson.walk(comando)
            print(anderson.Anderson.map_area)
```

Anderson.py

```
class Anderson:
    icon = ''
    comando = ''
    map_area = list("A                    Carro")
    resultado = ''

    def __init__(self, icon, map):
        self.icon = 'A'
        self.map = map

    def walk(comando):
        icon = 'A'
        map_area = list("A                    Carro")
        resultado = ''

        if comando == "D":
           for items in map_area:
                map_area.remove(resultado)
                joining = "".join(map_area)

    def print_map():
        print("A                    Carro")
```

That's it from now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like its just telling you `resultado = ''` isn't in `map_area.remove(resultado)`

Comment: There are variables not used... `items`, `joining`...  How is this supposed to do anything?

Comment: the error disappeared but my problem still the same :^)

Comment: Those unused variables are from a code online, I'm trying anything to remove those damn spaces

Comment: See my answer: you aren't trying to remove spaces.  `resultado` is an empty string.

Comment: `anderson = Anderson` should be `anderson = Anderson()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of problems with this, I can't go through them all, but they major one was not really understanding classes(forgetting self everywhere). You also didn't understand how `list()` works on a string. It works now, but Anderson only goes one space at a time instead a tab. Also most of us don't speak spanish (I know a little) so for the future try to at least translate it. Heres the full code(I moved them to one file to reduce hassle).

```
class Anderson:

    def __init__(self, icon):
        self.icon = icon
        self.map_area = [self.icon, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',"carro"] 

    def walk(self,comando):
        resultado = ' '

        if comando == "D":
            self.map_area.remove(resultado)

    def print_map(self):
        map = ""
        for char in self.map_area:
            map = map+ char

        print(map)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    anderson = Anderson("A")
    print("Ajude o anderson a chegar até o carro!")
    anderson.print_map()

    for x in range(1, 12):
        comando = input("GO:").upper()
        if comando == "D":
            anderson.walk(comando)
        anderson.print_map()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's not spanish, is portuguese hahah I haven't asked this in the Brazilian StackOverflow because it's empty. I will try to improve my coding skills ;)

Comment: Oh, You're welcome I recommend you write basic class programs to understand syntax and usage of the class. (I was wondering why I couldn't understand the "spanish "at all)

Comment: I was trying to code it while I was at class just for mock a friend hahaha, but I liked how python works (Even not understanding at all sometimes), and I will put some effort in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to search for a null string; that will always fail, by definition of the `index` and `remove` methods.  Instead, look for a space character:

```
resultado = ' '
```

That will get you to the rest of the coding errors -- there are quite a few.

Also, you do not need to turn your string into a list.  Use the string `replace` method to replace the first space with an empty string.

---

I strongly recommend that you adopt incremental programming.  You've tried to write a lot of code without testing it, and you now have many things to debug at once.

Comment: I will search for incremental programming! It was easy to build the whole code, but this remove spaces thing is driving me crazy hahah

Comment: @MatheusCésar Writing the whole code is always easy, that's part of the problem. It's very easy to throw down large amounts of code when you don't do proper testing. It's much harder in the short term (but easier in the long run) to write small pieces and test them as you go.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I did that in the whole process. I wrote every method and then tested it. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @MatheusCésar: your code suggests that you did not do things incrementally.  There are at least four consecutive errors in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`map_area` is a list that has been given a string. More specifically the string `"A                    Carro"`.

When you give this string to the `list()` constructor you get

```
In [30]: a = list("A            Carro")

In [31]: a
Out[31]:
['A',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'C',
 'a',
 'r',
 'r',
 'o']
```

You have `' '` in the list, not `''`.

To solve this either call `remove` with `remove(' ')` **OR**

make `map_result = "A     Carro".split(" ")` to have your `remove` call work as-is

Comment: I tried the both ways, but none of them worked. I managed to delete de 'A' in the begining, but that didn't worked with the ' '